# Passing a proxy data source in Bond5 tableview/collectionview binding

Tags: ios, swift3, reactivekit

With `Bond 4.x` it was possible to pass my custom data source when binding a tableview to an `ObservableArray` in order to implement custom invocations of UICollectionViewDataSource methods (e.g. `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`) like this:

```
viewModel.dataSource.bindTo(collectionView, proxyDataSource: HeaderViewCreator()) { indexPath, dataSource, tableView
```

This is gone now in Bond5 as trying to use the `proxyDataSource` parameter causes a compiler error expecting a different argument label in the call.

Unfortunately I could not find a proper section in the migration guide and also I had a hard time understanding the documentation in that regard. `BNDTableViewProxyDataSource` and friends seem to be gone completely from the codebase.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView and UICollectionView now have properties `bnd_delegate` and `bnd_dataSource` of type `ProtocolProxy`. That type has a property `forwardTo` that you can set to receive delegate or data source callbacks that are not used by ProtocolProxy (i.e. Bond).

For example:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

  var tableView: UITableView

  func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.bnd_delegate.forwardTo = self
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.